# Problema con DetailView en Django

Tags: html, python, django

Estoy teniendo un problema con mi proyecto, el cual trata de una pagina para publicar objetos para vender, pero al entrar al detalle de una publicación, me salen todas las publicaciones. Y en la url aparece el id de la publicación que quiero acceder.

view.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):

template_name = 'posts/detail.html'
queryset = Post.objects.all()
context_object_name = 'post'
```

detail.html

```
{% block body %}
<div class="post-detail-container">
    {% include 'posts/post_card.html' %}
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

post_card.html

```
<div class="post-container">
    <div class="post-container-head">
        <a href="{% url 'users:detail' post.user.username %}">
            <img src="{{ post.profile.picture.url }}" alt="{{ post.user.get_full_name }}" height="35">
        </a>
        <p class="post-container-head-username">{{ post.user.get_full_name }}</p>
    </div>

    <h4 class="post-container-title">{{ post.title }} - <small>{{ post.created }}</small></h4>

    <img src="{{ post.photo.url }}" alt="{{ post.title }}" class="post-container-img" width="500">

    <h5 class="post-container-price">${{ post.price }}</h5>

    <p class="post-container-description">{{ post.description }}</p>

</div>
```

Imagen del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

path(
    route='',
    view=views.PostsFeedView.as_view(),
    name='feed'
),

path(
    route='posts/new/',
    view=views.CreatePostView.as_view(),
    name='create'
),

path(
    route='posts/<int:pk>/',
    view=views.PostsFeedView.as_view(),
    name='detail'
),
]
```

Comment: Tiene sentido, este es el QuerySet de la vista: `Post.objects.all()`, estas obteniendo **todos** los posts, no es necesario proveerle ese QuerySet, basta que la vista reciba el `pk` o `slug` del objeto, para que la misma vista se encargue de obtenerlo.

Comment: @JulioCesar lo pense, pero en el curso que tome lo hacian asi y andaba bien, ya voy a probar sacando el queryset y ver que pasa.

Comment: Bro, lo siento, tienes razón, leyendo el código fuente no es eso, lo que si, es que es innecesario lo del QuerySet, pero te debería funcionar, creo que el problema es el slug o el pk que pasas a la vista.

Comment: Por otra parte, no veo que tengas un bucle `for`, en el template de la vista `PostDetailView`, así que no se de donde salen todos los posts, adjunta todas tus URLs, a lo mejor hay un problema de coincidencias.

Comment: Ahi adjunte el archivo urls.py

Comment: Y la URL que apunta a la vista `PostDetailView`?? Adjunta **todas** las URLs....

Comment: Ya encontre el error, en la vista que iria PostDetailView, pase la vista del feed. Suele fallar jajaja

Comment: Ya decía yo, que raro XDD